# Looping over an array in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having trouble iterating through this api and displaying the data. You can see the sample api in here https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending. I would be really grateful if you help me

interface

```
export interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    market_cap_rank: number;
    thumb: string;
    large: string;
    score: number;
}

export interface Coin {
    item: Item;
}

export interface ResponseObject{
    coins: Coin[];
   
}
```

React Code

```
const TRENDING = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending'
const Home = () => {
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState<ResponseObject[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<ResponseObject[]>(TRENDING).then((response) => {
      setTrending(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  return {response.coins?.map((p) => {
          return <div>{p.item.name}
</div>;
}

export default Home
```

Sample Api

```
{
   "coins":[
      {
         "item":{
            "id":"superfarm",
            "name":"SuperFarm",
            "symbol":"SUPER",
            "market_cap_rank":235,
            "thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coi1613975899",
            "large":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins
            "score":0
         }
      }
   ],
}
```

Comment: You are rendering an empty div in the Home component. What do you expect?

Comment: What are you seeing in console ?

Comment: I guess like problem is that your initialValue in useState is an array, but u get an object after axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from axios you get an array of ResponseObjects and then you set it to the "trending" field.  But then in your return statement you treat it like a single object...

Perhaps you need to do something like

```
return {trending[0].coins?.map((p) => {
          return <div>{p.item.name}
</div>;
```

So that you grab the first item.

Also I am not sure if this is an error but your return statement references the "response" which is internal to the "then" clause when maybe it should be referencing the local state "trending".

Also in your axios call you expect an array ResponseObject[] and also in your useState you expect an array... But in your "Sample Api" it seems like it is a single object. So maybe changing ResponseObject[] to ResponseObject both in the axios call and in the useState and finally your code will end up looking like this:

```
const TRENDING = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending'
const Home = () => {
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState<ResponseObject>({})
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<ResponseObject>(TRENDING).then((response) => {
      setTrending(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  return {trending?.coins?.map((p) => {
          return <div>{p.item.name}
</div>;
}
```

Comment: getting this error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'coins' of undefined```

Comment: look at the name of the property i used trending not response.... also can you post the output of the console.log(response.data).. that way I can see for sure what the result of the axios call it

Comment: I did it, still the same

Comment: look at my updated answer and please add the output of the console.log(response.data) to the question

Comment: Can you go to the Api link you can see the data

Comment: There is a problem with Api, now I am gettng cors error

Comment: perhaps the cors error is because you are missing some http headers

Comment: @Tequila yeah your api is returning a single object and not an array.